Как сложить значения из QLineEdit и QLabel?
Делаю программу, где после ввода числа в QLineEdit и нажатия на кнопку, число из QLineEdit должно прибавиться к QLabel, но не как str(), а как int(). 
Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне сделать это.
Код:
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(300, 400)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 120, 20))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("font: 13pt \".AppleSystemUIFont\";")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 65, 160, 20))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(119, 221, 119);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 120, 120, 20))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.all_profit_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.all_profit_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(145, 120, 120, 20))
        self.all_profit_label.setObjectName("all_profit_label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 160, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 300, 24))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.add_functions()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "PerekupCalculator | v. 1.0.0"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите сумму:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Заработано всего:"))
        self.all_profit_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))

    def add_functions(self):
        ## self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.add_profit(self.lineEdit.text()))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_profit)

    def add_profit(self):
        all_profit = (int(self.all_profit_label.text)) + (int(self.lineEdit.text))
        self.all_profit_label.setText(all_profit)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


Также, нужно чтобы выполнять такую операцию можно было бесконечно раз. И еще, подскажите, как сделать, чтобы после нажатия на кнопку помимо того, что введенное число добавляется к сумме всех введенных, поле для ввода очищалось

НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

text : QString
Это свойство содержит текст label's.
...
Функции доступа:
QString   text() const
...


void QLabel::setNum(int num)
Устанавливает содержимое метки в виде обычного текста, содержащего текстовое представление целого числа.

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(300, 400)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 120, 20))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("font: 13pt \".AppleSystemUIFont\";")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 65, 160, 20))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(119, 221, 119);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 120, 120, 20))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.all_profit_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.all_profit_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(145, 120, 120, 20))
        self.all_profit_label.setObjectName("all_profit_label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 160, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 300, 24))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

#        self.add_functions()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "PerekupCalculator | v. 1.0.0"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите сумму:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Заработано всего:"))
        self.all_profit_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                 # !!!
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)                                              # !!!

        self.add_functions()
        
    def add_functions(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_profit)

    def add_profit(self):
        try:
# ---------------------------------------------------> vv <----------------
            all_profit = int(self.all_profit_label.text()) + \
                         int(self.lineEdit.text())
# -------------------------------------------> ^^ <------------------------
            #self.all_profit_label.setText(all_profit)
            self.all_profit_label.setNum(all_profit)
# ------------------------------> ^^^^^^ <----------------------------------
        except Exception as e:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 
                'Внимание! Что-то пошло не так!', 
                f'{e}')
            


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()                                                    # !!!
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    
    



@martysue3005 что не так?
